# Is there a way to tell bundler to always use the latest 'official' version of a gem?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I want my gem to use the latest version of a dependency gem, is it possible/wise?

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly wise, but not specifying a version is one way.

The problem is that when you do that you risk introducing unexpected dependency conflicts.

Comment: Bundler's usually really good about resolving dependency conflicts; I've seldom found that to be an issue.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser The issues come when different gems specifically require different versions. Agreed, not too common.

Comment: Won't bundle lock whatever the dependency gem version was current at the time in Gemlock file when I do run bundle install? I would like to have the latest version without running bundle update.

Comment: @dimus ... How would you get the latest version without getting the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

if you specify in your .gemspec file something like `s.add_depenedency 'dependent_gem', '>= x.x'` this will be the case. but only the first time bundle command and is ran cause it will lock the version from that point onward, until user does bundle update.